# cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option "-O3"

Tags: python, windows, cython, setup.py, cythonize

I want to build a project that uses various flags by type `-O3 -Wall -std=c++11` using `cython`, but I get an error:

> cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option

Maybe it is possible to replace compilation with VS with Cmake, or am I incorrectly specifying arguments in Windows?.

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension(name=f'{__name__}',
              sources=[f'file.pyx'],
              language='c++',
              extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11', '-O3'],
              ),
]

setup(name=__name__,
      ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are on Windows and use the MSVC compiler. Unlike gcc and clang, MSVC has no `-O3` optimization flag. On MSVC it should either be `/Ox` or `/O2`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/o-options-optimize-code?view=msvc-170) for more details.